# jQuery swipe on mobile using anoSlide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I make the slide swipe on mobile?

I am using the anoSlide: http://www.anowave.com/factory/anoslide/demo.html.

This is the code that triggers the slider next and prev.:

```
$('.carousel ul').anoSlide(
{
    items: 1,
    speed: 500,
    prev: 'a.prev',
    next: 'a.next',
    lazy: true,
    auto: 4000
})
```

Is it possible to trigger the next, prev button when swiping left or right?

So far I have this but its not working:

```
$('.carousel-contentList').on("swiperight",function(){
    $(this).anoSlide({next: next});
});

$('.carousel-contentList').on("swipeleft",function(){
    $(this).anoSlide({prev: prev});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next and prev properties are for associating a DOM element like a button. They are not methods for changing the current slide. Instead on swipe, you could trigger the click event of the prev and next buttons:

```
$('.carousel').on("swiperight",function(){
    $('a.prev').click();
});

$('.carousel').on("swipeleft",function(){
    $('a.next').click();
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8t48r7zo/)**